# Not Getting Payment Method Custom column in admin > sales > order

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I am tring to add **payment method custom column** in `admin > sales > order`
with overriding core file by

Copying

```
 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

to

```
 /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php.
```

with following code

```
$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_payment', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id',array('method'));
```

in **protected function _prepareCollection()**

```
 $this->addColumn('method', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Method'),
        'index' => 'method',
    ));
```

in `protected function _prepareColumns()`

with this getting blank column with heading Payment Method like in the image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this to get payment method

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
         $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
         $collection->join(array('payment'=>'sales/order_payment'),'main_table.entity_id=parent_id','method');
         $this->setCollection($collection);
         return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
         // end here //
    }
```

and in grid

```
 protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

 $payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();

        $methods = array();
        foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel)
        {
                $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
                $methods[$paymentCode] = $paymentTitle;
        }

        $this->addColumn('method', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Method'),
                        'index' => 'method',
                        'filter_index' => 'payment.method',
                        'type'  => 'options',
                        'width' => '70px',
                        'options' => $methods,
                ));
        // End here
    }
```

hope this will work for you