# Add column payment

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

Add column payment in order to magento administrator 1.9.1.

I would add a column stating what was the form of customer payment in the admin panel.

Comment: Pls describe your question

Comment: I hope to be clear, I'm from Brazil and I am using Google translator.

I want the grid "Sale -> Orders" show, in addition to information "status", "order" and etc, the form of payment went with credit card or ticket.

Comment: may be this will help u  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17403/add-column-to-admin-sales-orders-grid  also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801686/how-to-add-custom-column-in-sales-order-grid-in-magento

Comment: Thanks to the friend's comment above, I found that it helped me a lot !!!

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42107/not-getting-payment-method-custom-column-in-admin-sales-order

Comment: ....welcome....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically For the Sales Order grid Customization you can use here some links from external resources. But for that You Should Have to Basic Knowledge of Module/extension Development.

these are some free extension for u...
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-order-grid-1.html

this is some resource of admin order grid customization..

http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-orders-grid/
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

Comment: As I wanted something specific, that link helped me, but thanks to your help: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/42112/26829.
Thank you again!